# Opening a port on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ports

I am trying to open up port on my Ubuntu machine to allow me to connect the Mongo using an external program. I ran this which is the command line to open a new port:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

but when I ran this to check if the new rule was there...

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
```

...the new port wasn't in the list - any ideas?

Comment: Did you started Mongo deamon?

Comment: `iptables` only modifies the filtering rules in the kernel. What you want is a program listening on that port. As 
Mahmut Ali has mentioned, you probably want to start your MongoDB.

Comment: Why was this down voted? The question explained the problem and I had done all research I could find to get it working. What might be considered a minor oversight to some is not to others and this may well prove to be useful to someone one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mangodb instance was not started, apart from that ,`sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` gives the list ports that are active are being used now, first start your Mango instance `sudo service mongodb start`  , then run this command `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` if you find 27017 in the list, then `sudo iptables -L` chack your iptable rule is added or not. If it is in that list good else, `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT` 
you can get more details on mangodb port and traffic @ http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/

Answer (score 0):

In this case the Mongo config file needed updating to use port 27017. Once I had done this and restarted the service, the new port change was visible on in the list.