# Mongodb bind multiple ips

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongodb v4.2.3 for ubuntu, and i'm trying to bind localhost and my public ip, but i get an error every time i reload mongodb afther editing the configuration file.

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27017
```

the error while restarting mongodb:

```
Job for mongodb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mongodb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: what error do you get? Add it to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set mongod.conf bind\_ip with multiple ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109134/how-to-set-mongod-conf-bind-ip-with-multiple-ip-address)

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. You do not need to bind mongo to multiple ip addresses.

Binding to 127.0.0.1 be enough. At that point I believe you just need to configure your firewall to allow external traffic to access port 27017 on your machine. I've done similar things like on windows.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/#manage-and-maintain-iptables-configuration

Comment: Not working, i've already opened port 27017 in my firewall, but when i try to connect to it remotely, i get "connection refused"

Comment: here is someone who had a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788740/opening-a-port-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved.**

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

For single ip, because it's interpreted as number

```
bind_ip = "127.0.0.1,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

For multiple ip, because it's interpreted as string

Comment: Have you tried binding it to `0.0.0.0` or is that too broad?

Comment: Avoid binding to `0.0.0.0` otherwise everyone can connect to your db (if you have no password setted like most of the people).